Model to determine if certain company names are the same
So I was trying to look into models that could help determine if a company name is the same. So basically I have a dataset that lists a bunch of company names that different investment funds hold but every investment fund may have a different naming convention for the company name such as Apple Inc or Apple Common stock. Is there any model that can help determine if they are the same company name.  I Know this might just be beyond something I can do but I know chatgpt can do this really well I can pass it like 20 company names and it will tell me if they are all the same or not but obviously my dataset has 500,000 rows so I don't know anyway I can just pass that data to chatgpt and I have heard it fails on longer computations.
I looked into levenshtein distance and fuzzy matching but I feel like it fails when the string has stuff like common stock in the name even though as a human it is clear Apple inc and Apple Us common stock would refer to the same company.So any machine learning algorithm or models that could help me tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to look into them myself I just want a starting point as fuzzy matching and the levenshtein distance has not been very helpful unless I potentially find a way to remove common filler words such as common stock, ptd, lty etc. Thanks for any help :))
Edit Again: Here is a smaller demo.
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 

data = [
    "29METALS LIMITED",
    "29METALS LIMITED",
    "29Metals Limited",
    "29METALS LTD",
    "29METALS LTD.",
    "29METENTY LTD",
    "29 METALS COMMON STOCK",
    "29 METAL PTD",
    "29METALS",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Company"])

df["Cleaned_Company"] = df["Company"].str.replace("[^\w\s]", "").str.lower()


def match_names(name, group):
    for group_name in group:
        if fuzz.ratio(name, group_name) > 80:  
            return group_name
    return name

groups = {}
for name in df["Cleaned_Company"].unique():
    matched_name = match_names(name, groups.keys())
    if matched_name in groups:
        groups[matched_name].append(name)
    else:
        groups[matched_name] = [name]


group_number = 1
for group_name, group_values in groups.items():
    df.loc[df["Cleaned_Company"].isin(group_values), "Group"] = group_number
    group_number += 1

print(df)

Now the output is:



Company
Cleaned_Company
Group




29METALS LIMITED
29metals limited
1.0


29METALS LIMITED
29metals limited
1.0


29Metals Limited
29metals limited
1.0


29METALS LTD
29metals ltd
1.0


29METALS LTD.
29metals ltd
1.0


29METENTY LTD
29metenty ltd
2.0


29 METALS COMMON STOCK
29 metals common stock
3.0


29 METAL PTD
29 metal ptd
4.0


29METALS
29metals
5.0



From this we can see it identified 5 groups in actuality they are all the same company except the 29Mententy LTD. I hope this makes my post more clear, thanks :)
Edit 3:
Here's another example this is a snippet of the data from the input file:



Company




MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL


MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL


MOL MAGYAR OLAJ GAZIPARI


Mol Magyar Olajes Gazipari Nyrt


MOLINA HEALTHCARE


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


Molina Healthcare Inc


Molina Healthcare Inc


MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC


Molina Healthcare Inc



The output should then be these company names and a group number assigned for example the first 7 entries should have the same group number because they are the same company and the next 2 would have another group and the rest would have a different group number assigned to them.

Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Thanks! I have just updated it to show my attempt and what goes wrong with my attempt. Ah I just realised I don't really have any errors so maybe this was the wrong place to post sorry about that.

I hope this fixes it up, I added a small example. I know it's probably confusing as to how one should know that only 29mententy Ltd is different using an algorithm but as a human it seems obvious because we know the limited, ltd, common stock are all usually useless but I'm not sure if there are models that can also determine that.

So Company is input, Cleaned_company is just an in between step the actual output is the group column they should all be 1 here except 29METENTY LTD which would be 2. The way the number system works is just assign the first company with 1 and for every different company youd assign a different number so next one would be 2 and so on.

@Lypse I'm gonna need more data. All companies are in data? Do you have to separate them all with 100% accuracy?

Yes so data is a csv that has the column called Company Name which lists a bunch of company names. I am trying to group them based on if they are the same company and assign them a group number. I'm looking for 100% accuracy but that said obviously disregarding words like common stock, ltd would still mean 100 percent and if it's not 100% then it is fine to assign it a different number. Also, how would I post more data?

We have done this earlier using rapidbuzz and tokenizer. But I can't see how your data looks like.

It's not clear how your data looks like.
I guess you have a large text. If the text is too large, KMP is a choice to look into, it is fast, but you could maybe solve the problem much easier. Because the number of companies out there are limited. Right?

KMP
KMP algorithm is difficult to explain. If you are interested to know how it works, please check the wikipedia.
Approach 1
def get_lps(p):
    lps, j = [0] * len(p), 0
    for i in range(1, len(p)):
        while j and p[i] != p[j]:
            j = lps[j - 1]
        if p[i] == p[j]:
            j += 1
        lps[i] = j
    return lps


def kmp(s, p):
    lps, indices, j = get_lps(p), [], 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        while j and s[i] != p[j]:
            j = lps[j - 1]
        if s[i] == p[j]:
            j += 1
        if j == len(p):
            indices.append(i - len(p) + 1)
            j = lps[j - 1]
    return indices


s = """"
some text Apple Stock common us inc
some text Apple INC Stock common us inc
some text Apple Inc. Stock common us inc
some text APPL Stock common us inc Apple APPLE
"""

print(kmp(s, 'Apple'))
print(kmp(s, 'Apple INC'))
print(kmp(s, 'Apple inc'))
print(kmp(s.lower(), 'apple inc'))
print(kmp(s.upper(), 'APPLE'))
print(kmp(s.upper(), 'NOTAPPLE'))


Prints
It prints the first index where the match is found:
[12, 48, 88, 154]
[48]
[]
[48, 88]
[12, 48, 88, 154, 160]
[]

Note
I'm assuming that the name of companies are known to you in advance, thus the variable pattern.

Approach 2 (Accuracy)
If you need 100% accuracy, then you have to find other ways to solve this problem, and fuzzy and "closeness" methods, will fail.
But, the number of companies are pretty limited. Right?
More accurate
It is not as simple as it looks. Because if you have 10,000 companies (let's just guess), then this would be difficult to write and maintain.
import re
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

pattern = r"(?i)(\d+\s*metals?\s+(?:limited|ltd|common.*)?)|(\bmol\b.*hungar.*)|(\bmol\b.*\bmag.*)|(\bmolina\b.*\bhealth.*)|(.*)"

s = """
29METALS LIMITED
29METALS LIMITED
29Metals Limited
29METALS LTD
29METALS LTD.

29METENTY LTD

APPLE 

GOOGLE



29 METALS COMMON STOCK
29 METAL PTD

29METALS
29METENTY LTD
29METALS Ltd
29METALS LIMITED
29METALS LIMITED
29Metals Limited
29METALS LTD
29METALS LTD.
29METENTY LTD
29 METALS COMMON STOCK
29 METAL PTD
29METALS
29METENTY LTD
29METALS Ltd

MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL
MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL
MOL MAGYAR OLAJ GAZIPARI
Mol Magyar Olajes Gazipari Nyrt
MOLINA HEALTHCARE
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
Molina Healthcare Inc
Molina Healthcare Inc
MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC
Molina Healthcare Inc

"""

memo = defaultdict(list)
companies = re.findall(pattern, s)

for i, (a, b, c, d, e) in enumerate(companies):
    if a:
        memo['G 1'].append((i, a))
    if b:
        memo['G 2'].append((i, b))
    if c:
        memo['G 3'].append((i, c))
    if d:
        memo['G 4'].append((i, d))
    if e:
        memo['G 5'].append((i, e))


pprint.pprint(memo)



Prints
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'G 1': [(1, '29METALS LIMITED'),
                     (3, '29METALS LIMITED'),
                     (5, '29Metals Limited'),
                     (7, '29METALS LTD'),
                     (9, '29METALS LTD'),
                     (24, '29 METALS COMMON STOCK'),
                     (26, '29 METAL '),
                     (30, '29METALS\n'),
                     (33, '29METALS Ltd'),
                     (35, '29METALS LIMITED'),
                     (37, '29METALS LIMITED'),
                     (39, '29Metals Limited'),
                     (41, '29METALS LTD'),
                     (43, '29METALS LTD'),
                     (48, '29 METALS COMMON STOCK'),
                     (50, '29 METAL '),
                     (53, '29METALS\n'),
                     (56, '29METALS Ltd')],
             'G 2': [(59, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125'),
                     (61, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125'),
                     (63, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125'),
                     (65, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL & GAS PLC COMMON STOCK HUF 125'),
                     (67, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL'),
                     (69, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL'),
                     (71, 'MOL HUNGARIAN OIL AND GAS PL')],
             'G 3': [(73, 'MOL MAGYAR OLAJ GAZIPARI'),
                     (75, 'Mol Magyar Olajes Gazipari Nyrt')],
             'G 4': [(77, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE'),
                     (79, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (81, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (83, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (85, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (87, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (89, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (91, 'Molina Healthcare Inc'),
                     (93, 'Molina Healthcare Inc'),
                     (95, 'MOLINA HEALTHCARE INC'),
                     (97, 'Molina Healthcare Inc')],
             'G 5': [(10, '.'),
                     (13, '29METENTY LTD'),
                     (16, 'APPLE '),
                     (19, 'GOOGLE'),
                     (27, 'PTD'),
                     (31, '29METENTY LTD'),
                     (44, '.'),
                     (46, '29METENTY LTD'),
                     (51, 'PTD'),
                     (54, '29METENTY LTD')]})



Edit
Since you have 30,000 companies:

You can first sort them.
Separate them by prefix.
Preprocess them. For instance, remove all the common words and suffixes (e.g., common, stock, preferred, LTD, Inc, INC., corporation, etc.)
Divide them roughly to 300 groups by prefix (e.g., companies with suffix 1 in group one, companies with suffix 2 in group 2 such as 29 metals... , and so on).
Then, you have roughly 100 companies per each category. You can write much simpler regular expression pattern for each category/group.
Every time you see a new company or a mismatch in your outputs, then you have to only modify the related pattern to that category/group.



Ah ye the 2nd approach output is exactly what I am after but as you said if there are a lot of companies it is not feasible and in my case there are around 30k unique companies.

@Lypse Updated. I don't have other ideas. Rolling hash will also fail. Look into tries to see if you can do something with tries.

Appreciate the idea, i'll look into it
